# Python - How to alternate between two loops?

Tags: python, image

I am curious how to alternate between two loops. The 1st loop takes a set of pictures. The second loop deletes all of them. I want to take pics, delete, take, delete infinitely (or at least for a very long period of time).

```
import time
import picamera
import webbrowser
import io
import os

frames = 60
deletecount = 0

def filenames():
    frame = 0
    while frame < frames:
        yield 'image%02d.jpg' % frame
        frame += 1
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
        camera.framerate = 60
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(1)

        start = time.time()
        camera.capture_sequence(filenames(),use_video_port=True)
        finish = time.time() #takes 60 pics

while deletecount < frames:

    if os.path.exists("/home/pi/image%02d.jpg"%deletecount):
       os.remove("/home/pi/image%02d.jpg"%deletecount)
       deletecount += 1
```

Comment: I don't think you've explained what your problem/issue is

Comment: If you are taking and deleting the same picture all the time, can't you put that into a single loop? `while True { take_picture(); delete_picture(); }`

Comment: You write an outer loop **while True:** that contains both of the inner loops.  That way, when you're done deleting one set of photos, you go back to take the next set.

Comment: Fixed the proble..@Prune thanks a lot, how did I forget that....

Comment: Thanks Austin too, yours works too.